# How to return a value in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am relatively new to Javascript and I really don't understand what I am doing wrong here but the return value is not being set :

```
found = _dataDictionary.findOne(findByModelNameQuery, function(err, result) {
    if (result) {
        if (result.record) {
            found = true
        } else {
            found = false
        }
    }   
    return found
});
```

Comment: You're probably using... asynchronous callback.

Comment: Did you call the function somewhere?

Comment: this is the 'complete' code I am using Model.observe('access', function(ctx, next, cb) {  
    var _dataDictionary = loopback.findModel('dataDictionary');

    found = _dataDictionary.findOne(findByModelNameQuery, function(err, result) {
      if (result) {
        if (result.record) {
          found = true
        } else {
          found = false
        }
      }    
      return found
    });
    ...
    set query.where based on the value found 
    .....
    
    ctx.query.where = query.where    
  }
  next();
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using callback functions (the function in the last parameter in findOne), to return results, I sugest to you to use a callback function.

To get the result, you may do something like:

```
function myFunction(myParams, callback){
     _dataDictionary.findOne(myParams, function(err,result){
         return callback(err,result);
     });
}
```

Then you can call "myFunction" in other place like:

```
...
myFunction(params, function(err,result){
       //do something with the result)
}
```

OBS1: if the params are an another function, the "ugly" way to do this is using nested callbacks, that usually are a "antipattern".

```
    function myFunction(myParams, callback){
     _dataDictionary.findOne(myParams, function(err,result1){
         _anotherAsyncFunction(result1.params, function(err,result2){
               //do something with result2 and callback it.
        });
     });
}
```

OBS2: You can avoid this antipattern using libraries such [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) "waterfall" method or [bluebird Promise Library](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html) "then" methods.

Comment: thanks everyone. Got it working :-)

Answer (score 0):

It *appears* that `_dataDictionary.findOne` is an [asynchronous function](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/async%20%26%20performance/ch1.md). So the value returned from the statement is not the same as the one assigned later inside the callback.

Refactoring your example will hopefully show you this:

```
_dataDictionary.findOne(findByModelNameQuery, function(err, result) {
  if (result) {
    if (result.record) {
      found = true
    } else {
      found = false
    }
  }

  // This statement returns to the `findOne` line executing this callback 
  // return found;

  // Instead you can log here to see the value
  console.log('FOUND', found);
});
```

**UPDATE:** based on your comments (and a few more assumptions) you could refactor to provide the value back to the calling function:

```
Model.observe('access', function(ctx, next, cb) {
  var _dataDictionary = loopback.findModel('dataDictionary');

  _dataDictionary.findOne(findByModelNameQuery, function(err, result) {
    if (result) {
      if (result.record) {
        found = true;
      } else {
        found = false;
      }
    }

    // Assuming cb is the method to return values if async
    cb(found);
  });

  // Assuming this is for async behavior to notify to the `observe` caller that this is an async callback
  next();
});
```